# A smart contract that receives USDT, not on ethereum

Tags: solidity, blockchain, gas, gas-price, usdt

Ethereum is pretty expensive so I'm looking for other blockchains where I can deploy a smart contract that can receive USDT and transfer USDT to other addresses. Are there any that user Solidity? what should I be aware of when I choose an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any blockchain that is Ethereum Virtual Machine(EVM) compatible to deploy your smart contract in solidity.

The thing you should be most aware of while choosing one the those blockchain is gas Price.

Some of the available alternatives of Ethereum blockchain are:

1. Polygon's POS Chain
2. Binance Smart Chain
3. Optimism Blockchain
4. Arbitrum Blockchain
5. Fantom's Opera Chain
6. Near's Aurora Chain
7. Avalanche Blockchain

According to me taking all factors like gas price, active users, degree of decentralisation and security into consideration **Polygon's POS chain** is best among all.

Comment: So if I choose Polygon, will I be able to get USDT from anyone, or just accounts that have USDT on Polygon? By the way, what about Algorand?

Comment: you can get USDT( which is a MRC-20 token on polygon blockchain) from anyone. There are lot of others stable coin polygon like USDC etc. Algorand is also quite good but not yet battle tested like polygon.

Comment: are you sure? There's no need for a specific bridge for each 2 blockchains?

Comment: you will obviously need a bridge to move your asset between different blockchains. I was referring to USDT present in polygon POS chain or any other MRC-20 token in general

Answer (score 0):

- Binance Smart Chain
- Polygon
  and there are several other chains.

Comment: And I'll be able to receive USDT from any account that has USDT, or only if it has USDT on the same blockchain as my smart contract?